# Unknown error with calling JSONP from within Phonegap and jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have following html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
        <script src="js/jq.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jqm.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jstore.js"></script>
        <script src="js/progressbar.js"></script>
        <script src="js/sql.js"></script>
        <script src="js/phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/sha512.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Start of first page: #one -->
        <div data-role="page">
            <!-- header -->
            <div data-role="header">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                        </td>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
                <center>
                    <span class="progressBar" id="pb1"></span>
                    <br />
                    Initial Syncronisation in progress!
                </center>
            </div>  
            <!-- footer -->
            <div data-role="footer">

            </div>
            <!-- /footer -->
            <script lang="text/javascript">
                document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
                function onDeviceReady() {
                   $("#pb1").progressBar();
                   $("#pb1").progressBar(5);
                   $.ajax({
                        url: 'https://url/user/'+$.jStorage.get("username","false")+'/modeSet/'+$.jStorage.get("password","false")+'/subSequence/'+hex_md5(new Date().getTime())+'.html',
                        dataType:'jsonp',
                        jsonp:'jsonp_callback',
                        jsonpCallback:'infoData',
                         success: function (data) {
                                alert('success');
                       },
                       error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            alert(thrownError);
                        } 
                   });
                }
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I call the page, I get an error with the code 200 and an additional alert box with the following content:

```
Error: infoData was not called!
```

It's running on a real Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 4.0.4. I have an Internet connection, but I have no clue where I'm going wrong.

The document returned by the server:

```
infoData({"validJsonDocument":"yes"});
```

I'm using Phonegap 1.4.1 with jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery mobile up2date

The other Libraries are actually not in use.

Comment: Did you forget to include the function definition for the infoData function in your question? I don't see that in your code.

Comment: I think you don't have declared the `infoData` function in your code.

Answer (score 1):

JSONP stands for JSON with Padding. The padding represents the function name that wraps around your JSON response when it's sent back to the client-side.

When the result is received, it's actually treated as if it were plain JavaScript, and is processed as such. Thus, the function wrapped around your JSON is called.

This means that in order for JSONP to work correctly, there must exist a function loaded in your DOM that matches the name of the function that wraps the JSON response.

Also, you've specified "infoData" as the name of your callback function using the ["jsonCallback" jQuery AJAX property](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
jsonpCallback    String, Function
```

> Specify the callback function name for a JSONP request. This value will be used instead of the random name automatically generated by jQuery. It is preferable to let jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it easier to manage the requests and provide callbacks and error handling. You may want to specify the callback when you want to enable better browser caching of GET requests. As of jQuery 1.5, you can also use a function for this setting, in which case the value of jsonpCallback is set to the return value of that function.

Try defining a function on the page called "infoData" that takes a single parameter, and this will get you past this error.

```
function infoData(jsonObj) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(jsonObj));  // print the raw JSON object
    alert(jsonObj.validJsonDocument); // access the property in your JSON object.
}
```

Alternatively, you can take the suggestion of the jQuery documentation and remove the jsonpCallback option completely and rely on the success callback you've already defined.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code to following:

```
<script lang="text/javascript">
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            function onDeviceReady() {
               $("#pb1").progressBar(5);
               $.ajax({           
                    url: 'http:url/jsonp.html', 
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    jsonp: 'callback',
                    jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
                    success: function (data) {
                            $("#pb1").progressBar(25);
                            alert(data.version);
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }                       
                }); 

            }
            function jsonpCallback(data){
                alert(data.message);
            }
        </script>
```

If I open the Page in Google Chrome, it works without a problem.
If I open it in the android browser it does the same thing.
Gives me an error 200 and says I jsonpCallback was not called.
I don't really know why the script gives me such a hard time.
Chris